# Incompatible type for argument of strcpy and strcmp

Tags: c, string, pointers, data-structures, incompatibletypeerror

(All strings)I need to check whether a given username(Item) is already logged in by comparing it with a Queue of logged usernames.But when I try to campare them with strcmp i get the error in the title.Later I also have a strcpy to add the username in the Queue with the same error.How can I deal with these problems?

These are my structs

```
typedef struct{
    char userid[8];
}QueueElementType;

typedef struct QueueNode *QueuePointer;

typedef struct QueueNode
{
    QueueElementType Data;
    QueuePointer Next;
} QueueNode;

typedef struct
{
    QueuePointer Front;
    QueuePointer Rear;
} QueueType;
```

Code to check given username in the Queue

```
boolean AlreadyLoggedIn(QueueType Queue, QueueElementType Item){
    QueuePointer CurrPtr;
    CurrPtr = Queue.Front;
    while(CurrPtr!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(CurrPtr->Data,Item.userid) == 0){
            printf("You have logged in to the system from another terminal.New access is forbidden.");
            return TRUE;
        }
        else CurrPtr = CurrPtr->Next;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Adding the given username to the Queue

```
void AddQ(QueueType *Queue, QueueElementType Item){
    QueuePointer TempPtr;

    TempPtr= (QueuePointer)malloc(sizeof(struct QueueNode));
    strcpy(TempPtr->Data,Item.userid);
    TempPtr->Next = NULL;
    if (Queue->Front==NULL)
        Queue->Front=TempPtr;
    else
        Queue->Rear->Next = TempPtr;
    Queue->Rear=TempPtr;
}
```

Comment: if(strcmp(CurrPtr->Data,.. Data is not const char* which is required by strcmp()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strcpy(TempPtr->Data,Item.userid);
strcmp(CurrPtr->Data,Item.userid)
```

Here `Data` is of type `QueueElementType`.

But `strcpy` and `strcmp` takes `\0` terminated `char *` as argument.

Change it to.

```
strcpy(TempPtr->Data.userid,Item.userid);
strcmp(CurrPtr->Data.userid,Item.userid)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.Indeed i needed a conection to userid.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
strcmp(CurrPtr->Data.userid,Item.userid)
```

as `strcmp()` expects argument of `const char*` but `CurrPtr->Data` is of `QueueElementType` type not of `const char*` type. From the manual page of [strcmp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html).

> int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);

Same applicable in `strcpy()` also. This

```
strcpy(TempPtr->Data,Item.userid);
```

make as

```
strcpy(TempPtr->Data.userid,Item.userid);
```